# Where is the stdio.h file located in Linux while using the gcc.7.2 compiler?

Tags: linux, gcc, location, stdio, include-path

I can't find the `stdio.h` file. I am using Linux Mint 18.2 XFCE and gcc-7.2 compiler.

Here is output of `find . -type f -name stdio.h`

```
smit@smit-Aspire-5742:/usr/lib/gcc$ find . -type f -name stdio.h
./i686-w64-mingw32/5.3-win32/include/ssp/stdio.h
./i686-w64-mingw32/5.3-win32/include/c++/tr1/stdio.h
./i686-w64-mingw32/5.3-posix/include/ssp/stdio.h
./i686-w64-mingw32/5.3-posix/include/c++/tr1/stdio.h
./x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3-win32/include/ssp/stdio.h
./x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3-win32/include/c++/tr1/stdio.h
./x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3-posix/include/ssp/stdio.h
./x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3-posix/include/c++/tr1/stdio.h
```

I don't want the mingw files. It's a cross compiler that I rarely use. I can't find gcc-7.2's `stdio.h` file. Am I looking in wrong directory?

Comment: Use `locate` to find files...

Comment: @MarcGlisse Means???

Comment: There is that thing called g**gle, if you type locate+linux in it, it gives plenty of information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong location. `stdio.h` is not located in `/usr/lib/gcc` but in `/usr/include`

`<>` Is basically a shortcut to `/usr/include` (or any directory you specify after the `-I` compiler flag) in C/C++. So

```
#include <myheader.h>
```

would include `/usr/include/myheader.h` and

```
#include <file/otherheader.h>
```

Would include `/usr/include/file/otherheader.h`
This means that since you normally include `stdio.h` with

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

the location would be `/usr/include/stdio.h`

Answer (score 0):

By default, gcc looks in different directories :

```
 /usr/local/include
 libdir/gcc/target/version/include
 /usr/target/include
 /usr/include
```

You can take a look at [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.1/cpp/Search-Path.html).

Answer (score -1):

It's an .h file it is a header, thus,
/usr/include/stdio.h
?

Comment: @SMIT PATIL: sry, a typo